# Create Mock for a constant method in Turtle

Tags: c++, mocking, turtle-mock

I have,

```
class CFoo : public CFooPar
{
   public:
      CFoo(){}
      ~CFoo(){}

      virtual bool ret() const
      {
         return true;
      }
};
```

How can I create mock class for this virtual bool ret() const method?

Thank you!

Comment: The question is a bit vague, could you elaborate what's your goal?

Comment: Is this question intentionally tagged with "[tag:turtle]", the RDF syntax?

Answer (score 10):

I use Google Mock for that (https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/V1_6_ForDummies).

With that tool, the mock reads

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
class MockCFoo : public CFoo {
    public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(ret, bool());
};
```

Comment: The question is specifically about `Turtle` library, not Google Mock.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean using [turtle](http://turtle.sf.net) here it is :

```
#include <turtle/mock.hpp>

MOCK_BASE_CLASS( MockCFoo, CFoo )
{
    MOCK_METHOD( ret, 0 )
};
```

The rest depends on how you use CFoo in your production code, however it would likely be similar to the [turtle motivation case](http://turtle.sf.net/turtle/motivation.html) I suppose.